# Aligning header to the right in ConTeXt

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, context

I am typesetting a novel in  ConTeXt and one of the things I was in need was a way of typesetting headers for scenes. A scene as I understand it, is simply a couple of lines which separate paragraphs, however when there is a change of setting, I remark so, like:

> Nobody will say that...
>
> -> Dead Man Creek, Indiana United States
>
> As our hero tried to...

The line 'Dead Man Creek...' informs the reader of a change of setting as well as scene. I have tried to model this by defining a new header, modeled on the subject header:

```
\definehead[scene][subject]
\setuphead[scene][style=slanted,align=right]
```

But I also need this text to be aligned to the right, but I can't seem to find a way to achieve this, though I have successfully centered the text.

Comment: Also see http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Right_and_left

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `flushright` instead of `right`:

```
\setuphead  [subject] [align=middle]

\definehead [scene]   [subject]
\setuphead  [scene]   [style=slanted,align=flushright]


\starttext

Nobody will say that...

\scene{Dead Man Creek, Indiana United States}

As our hero tried to...

\stoptext
```

[image]